# Getting "app restrictions" error in Instagram Basic Display API

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am calling the instagram API to authenticate like described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions/).

So I am calling (with correct instagram-app-id and redirect-uri):

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
  ?client_id={instagram-app-id}
  &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
  &scope=user_profile,user_media
  &response_type=code
```

But I get the following error/response:

```
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Cannot access app due to app restrictions"}
```

I got the necessary instagram_graph_user_profile and instagram_graph_user_media permission approved (via App Review for Instagram Basic Display).

I can not find anything regarding this "app restrictions" error. I have no app restrictions set up. What could possibly cause this error?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/624062398151157/

Answer (score -2):

I don’t have Facebook, what does it say about this error? Getting the same one